# I'm to use linux command in jsp... but page is infinity loading

Tags: linux, jsp, command

my source is below

```
<%@ page language="java"
import= "java.io.*,java.util.*" 
contentType="text/html;charset=EUC-KR" session="false" 
%>

<html>
<%  
try{
Process ps = null;

ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","ec2-user"});
ps.waitFor();

ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cd"});
ps.waitFor();

ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"mkdir","/home/ec2-user/hello"});
ps.waitFor();

}catch(IOException ie){
  ie.printStackTrace();
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</html>
```

when it is executed, page is infinity loading.

why can't use this command ?

ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","ec2-user"});

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark: Maybe `su` is waiting for a password.